# postgres COPY - long running or hanging?

Tags: postgresql

I'm migrating a postgres database to another machine.

I've used

```
pg_dump -a -t
```

To export each table (data only) and have used psql to load each file into the new database.

One of the files is either taking a very long time or it's hanging. How do I tell which, and how do I cure it?

- The file is large (20 Gbytes) but other larger files have loaded without problems in a couple of hours.
- I've tried recreating the export file several times to no avail.
- Larger files have loaded in a couple hours, I've waited for up to 12 hours to see if this one will finish.
- All the other files have loaded ok
- No sign of any shortage of space.
- No sign of any error messages

Is there any way of validating the export file prior to loading it? (it's too big to check with conventional text editor). is there any way of checking if the process really has hung or it's just taking a long time? Is there any way of using the *pg_dump* command with a WHERE clause, so I can try transferring the table in multiple blocks?

Thanks

Comment: Check `pg_stat_activity` to see if pg_dump hangs

Comment: Investigate `pg_dump -j` for parallel execution (jobs). This may increase performance.

Comment: As an alternative to `pg_stat_activity`, you could check `pg_locks` for locks. You can also look if the backend process that belongs to the `COPY` statement is consuming CPU or not.